# Loading jScrollPane after initializing Facebook Comments - how?

Tags: facebook, jscrollpane

Is there an "onComplete" state or similar for the Facebook Comments plugin? I'm trying to add a jScrollPane scrollbar to a content box that has FB Comments inside it. What happens is I get the FB Comments iframe placed on top of the box's content (as if it had an absolute position / was floating. Guessing this has to do with FB Comments initializing after jScrollPane.

Edit:

Now what I'm really after is combining ColorBox, Facebook Comments and jScrollPane and the headache starts pretty soon:

```
$('.mybox').colorbox({  innerWidth: 640, innerHeight: 480, scrolling: false, onComplete: function() {
    $('#cboxLoadedContent').jScrollPane({
// Init FB Comments here instead? Then call jScrollPane?
      showArrows: true,
      scrollbarWidth: 15,
      scrollbarMargin: 0
      });
    }, 
    onClosed: function() {
// What would happen here if I need to listen for FB Comments also?
      $('#cboxContent').jScrollPaneRemove(); 
    }
    });
```

Sorry if my question is a bit unclear, it's late and I've been in front of a screen for 10+ hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`xfbml.render`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function() {
    console.log('Loaded!');
});
```

Comment: Hm... Would you happen to know how to tie these two together with ColorBox?
I have a ColorBox, that when opened will include a Facebook Comment iframe. The box will also feature a jScrollPane.
Let me edit the original post and I'll show you what I mean.

Comment: Here's an idea...1) try reading the ColorBox documentation 2) inside this event trigger add your jScrollPane code needed...3) try it again...4) and again....5) if it didn't work...ask a new question **with** your code and explanation of what you've tried

Comment: Got it :) Thanks for filling in with that FB event snippet.